# Does specification implies that entropy map is upper semicontinuous?

Tags: ergodic-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and f a continuous transformation on X. f has the specification if one can always find a single orbit to interpolate between different pieces of orbits, up to a pre-assigned error. We call the map $\mu \to h_{\mu}(f)$ (Kolmogorov-Sinai entropy) the entropy map . 
  Does specification implies that entropy map is upper semicontinuous?

Comment: Your definition of specification sounds more like a definition of topological transitivity -- the key function of specification is to ensure that the time you spend going from one orbit segment to the next when you approximate is uniformly bounded.

Comment: This sounds a little bit like a homework exercise (my apologies if it's not).  A natural thing to do would be to write down a couple examples of systems whose entropy map is **not** upper semi-continuous, and see if you can find something from that list with specification.

Comment: Hi, dear Climenhaga, thank you for your answers. 

Answer (score 2):

Expansivity implies that the entropy map is upper semicontinuous. See P. walters book Thm 8.2.
I think that if the shadowing orbit in your definition of specification is unique then the map f is expansive.